# Force result for field as 'NULL' when document was posted after a certain date

Tags: sql, sapb1

I have a query that I am pulling in a department field, however, after a certain date I want this field to be populated as null.

For example, here is the code

```
    Select T6.Segment2 as 'Old Department Code'
```

I do want this field to pull in the appropriate values, however after a certain date ( 04/01/2019 ) I want this field to show a NULL value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which DBMS you are using but it is basically the same for all of them when it comes to this... You want to use a `CASE` statement.

What this essentially does is it acts as an `IF ELSE` in your `SELECT`.

So in your case (ha, pun) (T-SQL Syntax):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (YourDateFieldHere) < '04/01/2019' THEN (YourOutputFieldHere)
        ELSE NULL
    END (AS Alias)
FROM ...
```

`CASE` statements can check for multiple criteria, it doesn't have to just be one or the other, in this case just include more lines of `WHEN (something) THEN (display this)`

Comment: No problem, I appreciate you swapping your selected answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case..when`

( considering `YYYYMMDD` is the default format used in SAP at the internal level )

```
Select case when myDate >'20190104' then 
        null
       else
         T6.Segment2 
       end
       as 'Old Department Code'
  From yourTable
```